# Spring URL mapping conflicts

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, url, url-rewriting, mapping

At the moment I am bussy with implementing a new url structure for our webshop. The new url structure should be more optimized for search engines. We also want that our old structure will still be working and will use a 301 to redirect to a the new structure.

The problem is: the new structure sometimes conflicts with the old urls.

Example of the old url mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/brand/{categoryCode}/{categoryName}/{brandGroup}.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

New structure:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/brand/{brandGroup}/{superCategoryName}/{categoryName}.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

As you can see the url's have the same amount of values, so the old mapping will catch the new one and vice versa.

What is the best way to fix this? Using a url filter to rewrite the old ones to the new url structure?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [URL router in Spring MVC](https://github.com/bclozel/springmvc-router); you can define conflicting routes within your app and handle them with route prorities (first route to match the request wins) and refine request matching.

Your routes configuration file could look like:

```
GET /brand/{<[0-9]+>categoryCode}/{categoryName}/{brandGroup}.do oldcontroller.oldAction
GET /brand/{<[a-zA-Z]+>brandGroup}/{superCategoryName}/{categoryName}.do newController.newAction
```

Comment: The 0.6 version is 3.0.x compatible. And production approved. Check https://github.com/bclozel/springmvc-router/tree/springmvc-router-0.6

Comment: we use 3.0.2 and this one needs at least 3.0.3

Comment: Really? It should work with 3.0.x. It has no direct dependency on Spring.

Comment: it dont have this one: org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter

Comment: And org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod is added in 3.1.x ;)

Comment: HandlerMethod is only used in versions 0.7+.

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot, regular expressions can be used when mapping the `@PathVariable`, and this can be useful to resolve url conflicts:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PutMapping("/test/{id:^[1-9][0-9]*}") // id must be a number greater that 1
    public void method1(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody DataDto1 data) {
    }

    @PutMapping("/test/foo")
    public void method1(@Valid @RequestBody DataDto2 data) {
    }
}
```